# Sync a Palm Centro with a bad screen?

Tags: sync, palm, palm-desktop

My friend has a Palm Centro with a bad screen (can't see anything on it) but it seems to work otherwise.  (When I turn it on or off it makes all the right sounds)  Is there any way to sync it to a computer?  I haven't worked with a Centro in a while, but I seem to remember that it does not require you to tap anything in order to sync.  I have the cable.

Comment: Belated question:  Did it work?  If so, please tell us, and please also add a green checkmark to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The usb cable that comes with the centro has a sync button on it.  So you should be able to just hook it up and press the button.  It should beep when it starts, and again when its done.  This is assuming that you are using a computer that has been used to sync this phone in the past.  There may be some setup that you need to do that requires input on the phone to sync to a new computer.

Comment: It's a new computer.  Now what?

Comment: @JoelFan: Actually, I don't think you need to do any interaction even if it's with a new computer, because all you'll need to do is start the sync up at the times that the Palm Desktop installer tells you to.